# LINQ projection combining date and list

Tags: c#, linq, projection

I have a list of objects containg value and date of transaction.

```
DateTime Date { get ; set; }
double Value { get; set; }
```

I want to get the new grouped object which will contain date of transaction and list of values for this particular day.

I can retrieve both list and date but i dont know how to use projection to cast them into new object.

```
var res1 = ExpenseList.Where(p => p.Date == Convert.ToDateTime("01-12-2013"))
                      .Select(p => p.Value)
                      .ToList();

DateTime res2 = ExpenseList.Where(p => p.Date == Convert.ToDateTime("01-12-2013"))
                           .Select(p => p.Date)
                           .FirstOrDefault();
```

There might have been some confusion around I will post pictures to clarify

I have something like this in ExpenseList set of date and value

[image: What I have]

I want one Date and Collection of Values

[image: What I need]

Answer (score 3):

To group all of the values for a particular day you'll want to use `GroupBy`

```
var groups = ExpenseList.GroupBy(expense => expense.Date,
    expense => expense.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ExpenseList.Where(p => p.Date == Convert.ToDateTime("01-12-2013"))
           .Select(p => new MyObject {Date = p.Date, Value = p.Value})
           .ToList();
```

Replace `MyObject` for the actual type you have defined.